# reached end of file while parsing EVEN WITH all curly braces present

Tags: java

I'm new to java and running through the Java All-in-One for Dummies book.

I'm getting an error with HelloApp.java even though I copied it exactly from the book. Here it is copied & pasted directly from my .java file:

```
public class HelloApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    {
}
```

I get the following error:

```
HelloApp.java:7: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error
```

What gives?? I'm not missing any curly braces.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Even Notepad++ would have shown you this error. Are you coding in straight notepad?

Comment: You are using the wrong curly brace.

Comment: Yeah, I was coding in straight notepad. I just got Netbeans on my machine though. Shouldn't run into this anymore!

Thanks for the input everyone, much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You have two curly braces that don't face opposite of each other.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
{ // Reverse this curly.
```

Recall:  You may not be *missing* any curly braces, but that doesn't mean that they're all *correct*.  Typically, lower tier text editors, as well as IDEs can highlight mismatched braces, so I would encourage you to use this feature.

Comment: *forehead slap* Ay, can't believe I missed that. Thank you Makoto!